# database becomes read-only/Corrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In our application we have been using an encrypted sqlite database in db3 format that is downloaded from server and then again after processing is uploaded. The app is live and is used by several users.
Sometimes, very intermittently in one or two instances, the database gets corrupted. The user has to discard the entire application and reinstall again to work resulting in data loss.
Only once we could detect that one of the tables got missing from the database through no drop table command was written anywhere in the code.

Did anyone face this instance before? Any idea why does this happens?

Please note: The application is iPad application written in objective C.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason:
iDevices shut down quite a time before they'd actually run out of power.  Before your device shuts down your App will get notified that it's going to background, and then get notified that it's going to quit.  If you're handling those two notifications properly (i.e. closing all SQLite connections at one or the other) then you should not be getting database corruption.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan. I will check if the delegates are handled properly or not. But I am not sure it is due to power issues, since even if the application crashes, the user can perform various tasks in the ipad for a long time.